# Sum of products of elements in matrix form.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have two matrices $\textbf{A}$, and $\textbf{B}$ as follows:

$\begin{array}{c=c}
\textbf{A}
=
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
\end{array}\right]
\end{array}$
, and
$\begin{array}{c=c}
\textbf{B}
=
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13}\\
b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23}\\
b_{31} & b_{32} & b_{33}\\
\end{array}\right]
\end{array}$

I am looking for a way to write, in matrix language, this operation:

$(a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{21}+a_{13}b_{31})+(a_{21}b_{12}+a_{22}b_{22}+a_{23}b_{32})+(a_{31}b_{13}+a_{32}b_{23}+a_{33}b_{33})=k$

The matrices can be rectangular in such a way that $\textbf{A}$ can of mxn dimension and $\textbf{B}$ can be of nxm dimension. If this is possible, I would be grateful for a clue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if $C = A B$ is the matrix product, then the elements are $c_{i,j} = \sum_k a_{i,k} b_{k,j}$. Then the [trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace) of $C$ will be

$Tr(C) = \sum_k c_{k,k} = \sum_k \Big( \sum_l a_{k,l}b_{l,k}\Big)$

which seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: @ Yul Otani. This is what I was looking for. Thanks.